# Vue.js + Django + Login with Microsoft

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework, azure-active-directory, office365, azure-ad-msal

I have a SaaS application using Vue.JS as frontend and Django Rest Framework as backend. I use JWT tokens for authorizing between frontend and backend.

Now I want to add support for our customers to be able to sign in with their Microsoft accounts. So if the signed in user matches a user in our database, it is logged in to our application.

I've set up Azure B2C and can successfully log in and acquire a token in the Vue.JS application using msal library.
Then I send the token to backend server for verification. I use azure_ad_verify_token to verify the token, but I get an InvalidAuthorizationToken exception.

It seems to be working when the user is added to my organization's AD directory. But I would like to verify the token for any Microsoft user, then match it to users in our database. It would be too much work to manually add our customer's users to our AD directory. If it would be possible to add another organization/domain I guess that would be ok.

There's a lot of documentation regarding this but I always end up in examples for separate applications. Just to clearify flow I try to achieve.

1. The user clicks on login with microsoft
2. The user is redirected to Microsofts login page, approves my application for their organization
3. On requests sent to our backend, the token should be verified against Azure Active Directory using authorization class.
4. If the user's email exists in our database, the request is successful